# mongodb update reusing current value

Tags: javascript, mongodb, variables, mongodb-query, javascript-objects

I'm struggling to pass dynamically to the "replacedStatus" field the value that the charge had in the field status before it was replaced by the update of the query bellow. I tried to use a variable **$status** like it's used in aggregation queries but it didn't work, as the document it's being update with the value **$status** literally, not really the status before the update. I'm using the 2.6.9 version of Mongodb.

I'm trying this

```
db.getCollection('charges').
update({
  'supports.dest': ObjectId("5880eb0c426c9b0400e1016a"),
  "date": {
    "$gte": new Date(2017, 11),
    "$lt": new Date(2017, 12)
  },
  "status": {
    "$nin": ["Captured"]
  }
}, {
  "$set": {
    "status": "BillingSuspended",
    "replacedStatus": "$status"
  },
  "$push": {
    "logs": {
      "replacedStatus": "Captured",
      "date": new Date('2017-12-13T22:00:00.000Z')
    }
  }
}, {
  "multi": true
})
```

I'd appreciate guys if you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

The [$rename](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/update/rename/) operator is your friend here. The following should get you going:

```
db.getCollection('charges').
update({
  'supports.dest': ObjectId("5880eb0c426c9b0400e1016a"),
  "date": {
    "$gte": new Date(2017, 11),
    "$lt": new Date(2017, 12)
  },
  "status": {
    "$nin": ["Captured"]
  }
}, {
  "$rename": {
    "status": "replacedStatus" // rename status --> replacedStatus to capture old value
  },
  "$set": {
    "status": "BillingSuspended",
  },
  "$push": {
    "logs": {
      "replacedStatus": "Captured",
      "date": new Date('2017-12-13T22:00:00.000Z')
    }
  }
}, {
  "multi": true
})
```

Comment: I've got the following error @dnickless:                                                  

Failed to execute script.

Error: Fourth argument must be empty when specifying upsert and multi with an object. :
DBCollection.prototype._parseUpdate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:522:1
DBCollection.prototype.update@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:552:18
@(shell):1:1

Comment: My bad, I had some superfluous brackets in the solution. Please try again. I'm sorry.

Comment: thanks for trying to help me out @dnickless, but now I've got the following error:

"Cannot update 'status' and 'status' at the same time"

Comment: That seems like a Mongoose issue, also see here: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2593 Are you using an older version here?

Comment: I'm using mongo v3.4.5, it's quiet new, isn't it?

Comment: Which version of Mongoose, though? Have you tried running the query against MongoDB directly?

Comment: "mongoose": "3.8.26",
 "mongoose-validate": "0.0.5",

I didn't tried directly, just using Robomongo, because I need to find a way that works in Robomongo so other users can use

Comment: So you tried it using Robomongo? I'm surprised to hear that this doesn't work. I thought I had tried it... Anyway. Would splitting the query in two queries be an option?